# create column for auto-date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I know that to create a column in mysql is like this

```
 'date' timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

how to postgresql?

Comment: What did you try so far? And what error message did you get, if you got one...

Comment: Apart from the invalid identifier for the column name, that looks OK to me.

Comment: To clarify, 'single quotes' represent a literal string; to quote an identifier, you need "double quotes": `"date" timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or give your column a non-reserved name).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the same, you just have to fix the identifier quoting to use SQL standard `"identifer quoting"`:

```
 "date" timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

but really, you should *not* use `"date"` as an identifier.