# Retrieve all users with recent updates

Tags: sql

Sql question.

I have a customer table with:

```
User id, name, email, phone
```

The customer can update their name, email and phone at anytime on an app.

How can I find out which user id had changes in name, email or phone number on a particular date?

Comment: Since your table doesn't store the date that they made the changes, you can't. Add a LastModified column with a datetime type (or whatever your specific database product provides) and the problem becomes trivial. I'd give you a specific example, but because you didn't tell us what database engine you use, I can't guarantee to get the syntax right.

Comment: @ADyson Your comment should probably be an answer

Answer (score 3):

Since your table doesn't store the date that they made the changes, you can't.

If you add a column with a `datetime` type (or whatever your specific database product provides) - you could call it `LastModified` or something like that - then the solution becomes trivial.

I'd give you a specific example, but because you didn't tell us what database engine you use, I can't guarantee to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with RDBMSes, you cannot as they generally store say a "photograph" of your data in time not a "film" of how it got there.

Based on the RDBMS you use, you can introduce an updated_at field which will hold when the last change happened to that row either from the "UPDATE" statement (say 'UPDATE phone=000, updated_at=now() WHERE user_id=999') or set it up to autoupdate see: [create column for auto-date in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518399/create-column-for-auto-date-in-postgresql#23520639)